# Need more eyes for spotting the bug with compilation of doxygen on windows

Tags: cygwin, doxygen, visual-c++-2008

**Summary:**

```
1>Executing Lex for d:\usr\doxygen\src\code.cpp ...
1>flex: can't open ..\src\code.l
1>Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Executing Lex for d:\usr\doxygen\src\code.cpp ..."
```

**Details**

I am compiling occasionally the sources of Doxygen (http://www.doxygen.org/) to publish its Windows binaries from SVN versions. The Visual Studio C++ 2008 (i.e. version 9) is used for the purpose. As Doxygen sources use also yacc and lex tools, the cygwin bison and flex was used succesfully in the past. It stopped to work. Namely, the flex complains it cannot find its source (as shown in the summary above). The version of flex on my computer is:

```
d:\>flex --version
flex 2.5.35
```

The VS project `winbuild\Doxygen.vcproj` is configured to launch flex, and the Visual Studio apparently generates a batch file for the purpose. The Build Log contains the following:

```
Creating temporary file "d:\usr\doxygen\winbuild\Debug\BAT00000241406084.bat" with contents
[
@echo off
flex -PcodeYY  -od:\usr\doxygen\src\code.cpp  ..\src\code.l
if errorlevel 1 goto VCReportError
goto VCEnd
:VCReportError
echo Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Executing Lex for d:\usr\doxygen\src\code.cpp ..."
exit 1
:VCEnd
]
Creating command line "d:\usr\doxygen\winbuild\Debug\BAT00000241406084.bat"
```

When trying the command manually from command line, I can really observe the same:

```
d:\usr\doxygen\src>flex -PcodeYY  -od:\usr\doxygen\src\code.cpp  ..\src\code.l
flex: can't open ..\src\code.l
```

However, when replacing backslashes at the path to the `code.l` by normal slashes, it works:

```
d:\usr\doxygen\src>flex -PcodeYY  -od:\usr\doxygen\src\code.cpp  ../src/code.l
```

I am not sure if the problem with backslash vs. slash in the flex version is the newly introduced bug/feature or not. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Cygwin doesn't support paths with backslashes. Can should try with GNU Win tools instead http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html as suggested in the installation chapter of the doxygen manual.

Comment: Hi Dimitri. I did try and it did not work for me. Actually, cygwin does support path with backslashes -- it only warns that I should use POSIX paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried harder and found the reason. The `cygwin` actually worked for me in the past. And it still works with backslashes -- it only displays a warning about better using he POSIX paths.

The reason was, that I have installed more tools that brought more `flex.exe` utilities. The first is the part of the `msysGit` installation, and the second one is from the *Ruby Development Kit*. Both of them do not support backlashes in paths. The Doxygen started to compile again after renaming them.

The truth is that the GnuWin `flex.exe` consumes backslashes without any warning -- I am prefering it now.